# Missing route parameter for Route URI using Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, routes, laravelcollective

I'm trying to create a Laravel Notification. I created a table called `send_profiles`. When a Candidate is logged in and searching through jobs, he can send his job profile to the employer. All of that data is in a table called `job_seeker_profiles`. I'm developing a Job Search type of application.

I created a new Notification class called `SendProfile.php`:

```
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        return [
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'employer_profile_id' => DB::table('send_profiles')->where('user_id', $user->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->offset(0)->limit(1)->get('employer_profile_id'),
        ];
    }
```

I don't know the best way to go about this but anyway this is my route.
web.php:

```
Route::get('/admin/job-seeker/search/employer/{employerId}/post-a-job/{jobPostId}/send-profile', 'AdminEmployerJobPostsController@sendProfile')->name('admin.employer.post-a-job.show.send-profile')->middleware('verified');
```

AdminEmployerJobPostsController.php:

```
public function sendProfile($employerId, $jobPostId)
{

    $user = Auth::user();

    $jobSeekerProfile = JobSeekerProfile::all()->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();

    $employerProfile = EmployerProfile::limit(1)->where('id', $employerId)->get();

    $jobPosts = JobPosts::all();

    $jobPost = JobPosts::findOrFail($jobPostId);

    $user->sendProfile()->create();

    $employerProfile->notify(new SendProfile());

    return back()->with('send-profile', 'Your Profile has been sent!');

}
```

This is my error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.employer.post-a-job.show.send-profile] [URI: admin/job-seeker/search/employer/{employerId}/post-a-job/{jobPostId}/send-profile]. (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/highrjobs/resources/views/admin/employer/post-a-job/show.blade.php)

show.blade:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('pageTitle', 'Create a User')

@section('content')

    @include('includes.job_seeker_search_employers')

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal5">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{ $jobPost->job_title }}</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h5>{{ $jobPost->job_description }}</h5>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'AdminEmployerJobPostsController@sendProfile', 'files'=>true, 'style'=>'width: 100%;']) !!}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::hidden('user_id', Auth::user()->id, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::hidden('employer_profile_user_id', $employerProfile->id, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            {!! Form::button('Back', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-block float-left', 'data-dismiss'=>'modal']) !!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            {!! Form::submit('Send Profile', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block float-right']) !!}

                            {!! Form::close() !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br><br><br>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@stop
```

If I remove the form, I at least don't get an error. So I actually think there is an issue with the form.

To be clear, all I want is to insert the `user_id` and the `employer_profile_id` into the `send_profiles` table and then send a notification to the employer.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the notification, but on that topic: why are you saving things to the database instead of passing them to your notification when you create it? See [this example](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/CanResetPassword.php#L27) of sending a notification in the base code, and then see how [the notification class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php#L38) handles it.

Comment: Are you saying all of the notifications data should be in the notifications table only?

Comment: I'm saying you can pass things directly to the notification when you create it, instead of doing more database lookups. You should really be aiming to minimize database access, so if you already have information, use it.

Comment: Yes, that's why I just want to pass a user_id and an employer_profile_id, so I know which Candidate sent a form request to which Employer.

Comment: I tried watching a YouTube video on notifications. I feel very confused about this topic.

Comment: Last question. How can I save the data in my form into the notifications table?
$user->notifications()->create($input); ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Where? Is there a Notifications Model?

Comment: I’m not following. I assume if you have created a table that you have also created a model to go with it?

Comment: Yes, I did and I added the $fillable columns to it. I'm getting a new error now...
Call to undefined method App\SendProfile::via(). Should I ask a new question at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route specifies a GET request to a URL that contains certain parameters:

```
/admin/job-seeker/search/employer/{employerId}/post-a-job/{jobPostId}/send-profile
```

Your form is using `AdminEmployerJobPostsController@sendProfile` as an action; this is translated into a URL by searching the route list, and choosing what Laravel thinks is most appropriate. Since you haven't passed anything to fill the `employerId` and `jobPostId` parameters, you're getting this error when the URL is generated.

Even if you could get the URL generated, you'd have a problem because your form is sending a POST request to this GET route.

What you need to do is ensure you have a POST route pointing to a new controller method. You won't pass any parameters to this route in the URL, so your controller method will only typically accept a `Request` object as a parameter. Second thing you should do is specify your form's target more accurately. Pass in the route name instead of making it guess.

```
public function sendProfile(Request $request)
{
    // you get this here so no need to pass it in the form
    $user = Auth::user();

    // your relations should be set up so you don't need to do this:
    // $jobSeekerProfile = JobSeekerProfile::all()->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
    // instead do this:
    $jobSeekerProfile = $user->jobSeekerProfile();

    // a simple find is much neater than what you had
    $employerProfile = EmployerProfile::find($request->job_seeker_profile_user_id);

    // not sure why this is here?
    $jobPosts = JobPosts::all();

    // also your form isn't passing a job post ID
    $jobPost = JobPosts::findOrFail($request->jobPostId);

    // ??? creating an empty something?
    $user->sendProfile()->create();

    $employerProfile->notify(new SendProfile());

    return back()->with('send-profile', 'Your Profile has been sent!');

}
```

Comment: I decided to put things in a new controller and use the store method, but are you saying the notification data should be in the Notifications table only? That makes sense. Also thank you, I see all of the mistakes I made above. I did edit my original thread and code though.